# To get sample Issuer Script Template 1(Tag 71) value

Tags: emv

I would like to get sample Issuer Script Template 1(Tag 71) or Issuer Script Template 2(Tag 72) value for testing the Kernel Application.
Thanks for the help....

Answer (score 3):

In order that not just anyone pass some issuer script to a card and change its counters, SMI Secure messaging for Integrity( to make sure the data is not altered) and SMC - Secure messaging for confidentiality (to make sure none other can read) is used. Read EMV Book 2 Section 9
 Secure Messaging for this.

Once you are done with this part, you can check Book 3 on what script you need to pass to the card. 
[image]This is packed in a Template 71 or 72 for the below reason.

- Issuer scripts with tag '71' shall be processed prior to issuing the
  final GENERATE AC command.
- Issuer scripts with tag '72' shall be processed after issuing the
  final GENERATE AC command.

Since this involves a MAC( based on your SMI Session Key) and a Cryptogram( based on SMC Session Key), I don't think a sample would help.

[image]

[image]
[image]